# Chrome browser closes automatically after the program finishes in cucumber webdriver - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I'm using Chrome: 57.0, ChromeDriver: 2.26, selenium-webdriver: 3.4 and cucumber 2.4.
I'm performing test automation, I'm using the Ruby language with the webdriver and cucumber frameworks in ubuntu 16.04.
When I finish testing the browser, Chrome closes the browser.
Why is this happening? Or am I forgetting something? I am using the following code. Any help is appreciated.

```
Dado(/^que eu esteja na página principal da loja$/) do
  @navegador = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
  @navegador.manage.window.maximize
  @navegador.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 5
  @navegador.get 'http://automationpractice.com/index.php'
end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chrome browser closes automatically after the program finishes in ruby using watir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42354533/chrome-browser-closes-automatically-after-the-program-finishes-in-ruby-using-wat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, the chrome browser instance is terminated when chromedriver exits.  But you can use `desired_capabilities` to change that behavior:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(:chrome_options => {detach: true})
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
driver.navigate.to "http://example.org"
```